# Why is manual autowiring not working in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jpa

I am working with an application which has multiple databases configured in Spring Boot per this tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Multiple databases (Oracle Teradata etc) are setup with the typical @Entity, Repository and Configuration classes with @EnableJpaRepositories annotation to set up the configuration, like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.baeldung.multipledb.dao.product", 
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "productEntityManager", 
    transactionManagerRef = "productTransactionManager"
)
public class PersistenceProductConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean productEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
          = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(productDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
          new String[] { "com.baeldung.multipledb.model.product" });

        
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
          env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.dbprops")
    public DataSource productDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager productTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
          = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
          productEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**Requirement:**
Above connects to databases during startup, but I want to connect them after the startup, inside a controller like below on user request:

```
/*LOGIC BELOW IS ALTERNATIVE TO CLASS PersistanceProductConfiguration ABOVE*/
@RestController
public class RestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/student/{studentId}")
    public Student getTestData(@PathVariable Integer studentId) {
        ensureConnectionExists();
        return ResponseEntity.ok("");
    }

    public void ensureConnectionExists() {
        if(!connectionExists){
        //================
        // ESTABLISH THE CONNECTION HERE
        //=================
        }
    }
}
```

Effort:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


public void ensureConnectionExists() {
    if(!connectionExists){


    Datasource datasource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
    .username("jdbc.user")
    .password("jdbc.pass")
    .url("jdbc.url")
    .driverClassName("jdbc.driver")
    .build();

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
          = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(productDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
          new String[] { "com.baeldung.multipledb.model.product" });

        
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
          env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
          = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
          productEntityManager().getObject());
        

        AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory - applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        factory.autowireBean(transactionManager);
        factory.initializeBean(transactionManager, "JpaTransactionManager");


    }
}
```

Question:
Why is the above effort manual auto wiring not working?
The code is hit on breakpoint, but the system does not autowire the bean and/or accomplish the connection to the database.

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe that manual autowiring part should be done on startup. What happens that makes you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: There is no autowiring, why do you want this to even happen instead of at startup?